# What type should be used to store year property in Core Data?

Tags: core-data, xcdatamodel

I thought of `Integer 16`, because it's easy to calculate years, depending from it.

`String` is good for searching, for ex. it's easy to find year 78 as substring from 1978. 
And it's also possible to keep year as `Date`.

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll stay with `Integer 16`, because it's the way how it's done in the book "CoreData for iOS".

Answer (score 1):

I would think that storing something that involves a date of some kind would be best stored as an `NSDate` simply because it's pretty likely that when you pull that value back out, it will be for displaying some kind of date. I can't imagine that XCode would go out of the way to make `NSDate` so accessible in Core Data unless they had a good reason.

It could also be optimization...

Lastly, it's all about the circumstance. Like you had stated: yes, sometimes saving an object as a string is wise for various reasons including searching. But to answer your question directly, I would go with `NSDate` predominantly.